# Error while building table using wice-grid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

Building a rails app and using wice_grid to build tables in my views. But getting this error 'undefined method `tag_options'' and have no idea what to do from here. Please help guys!

Comment: at least show use some of your code like what command you use to create a table (`rails g model field1:type`) or you scaffold the whole thing `rails g scaffold table_name field1:type field2:type ...`  is tag_option auto generated by rails or you add that in yourself

Answer (score 0):

You may use a fork to rails 5

https://github.com/patricklindsay/wice_grid